# Xamarin Forms iOS and Android very light weight (thin) font

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a large size label in my application and I have implemented this so that the font weight is less for the label:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Label xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=J" 
       x:Class="J.Templates.WordLabel" >
    <Label.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" Android="sans-serif-thin" iOS=".SFUIText-Light" />
    </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```

Does anyone know how I can implement a font on Android and iOS that has an even small weight?

Comment: You can refer to this [Fonts in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google fonts as per your requirement. from [here](https://fonts.google.com/)

Now add fonts to Android(Assets) set property as AndroidAssets and iOS(Resource) set property as BundleResource.

1)Add below code to App.xaml and provide the font name (in my case OpenSans-Regular).

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:Key="fontFamilyOpenSansRegular" x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="OpenSans-Regular" Android="OpenSans-Regular.ttf#OpenSans-Regular" /> 
</ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

2) Use DynamicResource to call the font as below.

```
<Label Text="Test" TextColor="#1db4d9" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="{DynamicResource fontFamilyOpenSansRegular}">
```

And its done.
Let me know if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

One extra thing you need to do for iOS is add an entry to your Info.plist.

[image]

The raw entry is:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>fontawesome.ttf</string>
    <string>Signika-Light.ttf</string>
    <string>ionicons.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Do I still need to do that if using a system font?

Comment: I think so - if it's a font you've added to _Resources_.